# Store list of strings at a time in redis using Jedis library

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I need to store the list of keys(strings) into the redis database and I am using the jedis library to store it. I have the below user defined java object.

```
Class Hello {
    List<String> keys;
    String name;
    String age;
    //setters and getters        
}

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
keys.add("a");
keys.add("b");

Hello hello = new Hello();
hello.setKeys(keys);
hello.setName("Hi");
hello.setAge("23");
```

In the above example, I have two keys a,b. For these keys other details are same like name and age. Currently I am inserting the values into the redis using jedis by iterating the values from the keys and storing the details sequentially like below

```
for(String keyValue: hello.getKeys()) {
    List<String> keySingle = new ArrayList<>();
    keySingle.add(keyValue);
    hello.setKeys(keySingle);

    String encodedValue = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(hello);

    final long ret = jedis.setnx(keyValue, encodedValue);//this will store for every key with an object as a value in the db

}
```

If I want to get the value for the Key "a" in the above example I will use the below method to retrieve:

```
String ret = jedis.get(lockKey);
```

In the same way, do we have any way to store the all the keys at a time with out iterating and storing the keys in the database.